# Separately working javascript makes Shower presentation blank out

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, click, jquery-animate

I hope this is not to vague. If so, please do say.

I am trying to get some interactivity into a [Shower](http://shwr.me/#) presentation. The script of the interactive diagram works fine on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/JJh9z/1/) as well as in a local html. As I copy the relevant bits into a section (class="slide") of the Shower-presentation-html-file it loads well.

But as I click on one of the time spans (buttons b2007 or b2016), to animate/crop the diagram, the page turns black. If I navigate back and forth with arrow keys I can return to the slide and I see that the script did work, because it does show me the chosen time span.

So what seems to be the problem ist, that when I call the .click(function) it somehow also calls something within the shower/shower.min.js. As I am a total beginner, I did not dare changing anything in there, rather hoping for you to have a brilliant idea.

```js
$('#b2007').click(function() {
  $('#trendcont').animate({
    width: '300px'
  }, 1000);
});

$('#b2016').click(function() {
  $('#trendcont').animate({
    width: '800'
  }, 1500);
});
```

```css
#trendcont {
  border: 0px solid #000;
  height: 350px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
to begin, click on one of the time spans.
<a href="#" id="b2007">2004-2007</a>
<a href="#" id="b2016">2004-2016</a>
<div id='trendcont'>
  <iframe scrolling="no" style="border:none;" width="800" height="800" src="https://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=de&q=Jatropha,palm oil&cmpt=q&tz=Etc/GMT-1&tz=Etc/GMT-1&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=800&h=800">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a working demo that I could try? It would make everything much easier. There’s also a big difference between Shower 1.x and 2.x, which one is yours?

Comment: i am using the latest shwr.zip from here: https://github.com/shower/shower/wiki/Quick-Start

what format are you looking for as a demo? more code or a zip-file?

The shwr-index.html is pretty forward. i just copied all the functioning code from above into the right places. main problem is, that screen turn black on mouse click.
follow-up question: is there a way to forward slides via mouseclick?